# How does CIFS work when opening a file?

Tags: cifs

After I mount a network drive using `mount -t cifs ... /mnt ...` on `/mnt` directory on a linux machine, how exactly does the system read files from it? Is it opened as a stream whenever an app requests the file contents, is it copied into some tmpfs or copied somewhere on a disk?

Comment: [The SMB specification is available here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb2/5606ad47-5ee0-437a-817e-70c366052962). Based on sections 2.2.20 & 2.2.21, it seems that the SMB client requests specific portions of data in a file, and the server returns exactly that. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Haxiel Thank you for responding. Partially answers. I wanted to know where is that portion of a file then stored? Where all does the linux map that file, to be precise. Is it somewhere on disk or tmpfs

Comment: The second paragraph of your question was uncalled for. I was very tempted to ignore your question because of it.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt The downvote was uncalled for, too. If you are not aware, just google "decline of stackoverflow" and see how we are all tired of the moderators' anarchy.

Comment: Be that as it may. But you do not make anything better by adding that kind of sulking comment to your question. If anything, it lowers the quality of your question, making it more likely to get downvoted. (Note: I did *not* downvote your question.)

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt I would question your theory in long term. I know you didn't downvote, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system sends the read request to the CIFS server, and passes the reply from CIFS server to the application that requested the read. All that happens in memory. Nothing is copied to any disk or tmpfs.

Comment: This isn’t 100% true.  You might want to look at the “Cache Coherency” section in your mount.cifs man page: https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Comment: Specifically, the Linux cifs kernel module uses the fscache to improve performance.  Modern kernels use a variety of tricks to cache files locally.

Comment: @jsbillings Thank you for pointing out. How would I disable that? I do want caching, but never on the disk, exclusively in ram. I see there an option "fsc" but I can only enable it, and it is automatically enables for read only files. I indeed want my mount to be read only. How do I prevent disk IOs then, but still save caching in ram?